# OnClick event to Removed ItemList from Android ListView

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, listview

I am creating an android application using Visual Studio 2022. I am using ListView to display the items added by the user (Name and quantity). What I'm trying to do is that when user clicked on any of the item in the list, it will removed the items from the ListView. However, from the code below, I am getting an exception at :

> string selectedItem = itemsList[e.Position];

How do I resolve this?

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_lotslist);
// Create your application here
string jsonData = Intent.GetStringExtra("transaction");
_transaction = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Transaction>(jsonData);

 private ListView _listView;
_listView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.myListView);
if (_transaction.Lots.Count > 0)
{
    _lotAdapter = new LotAdapter(this)
    {
        Lots = _transaction.Lots
    };
}
_listView.Adapter = _lotAdapter;
_listView.ItemClick += _listView_ItemClick;

}


private void _listView_ItemClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
// Get the selected item from the ListView
string selectedItem = itemsList[e.Position];

// Remove the selected item directly from the list
itemsList.Remove(selectedItem);

// Create a new ArrayAdapter and set it to the ListView
_listView.Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, 
Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, itemsList);

// Perform any additional actions if needed
Toast.MakeText(this, $"Removed Item: {selectedItem}", ToastLength.Short).Show();

}
```